# How to count best ranks for each user from one tabel and Insert/Update with results another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Ranking board for the best first 100 blogs for each gender Males and Females.

I have a blogs table:

```
PRIMARY
blogs_id  users_id  blogs_score  blogs_score_time      gender
    1         11        2852     2015-09-09 05:21:51     m <-- same score but older date
    2         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:31:54     m
    3         23        2146     2015-09-10 07:32:26     m
    4         23        2852     2015-09-10 04:42:15     m <-- same score but newer date
    5         51        1793     2015-09-11 08:15:55     f
    6         88        2947     2015-09-11 09:33:18     f
```

I have a users table:

```
PRIMARY
 id  best_rank  gender
 11      0         m
 23      0         m
 51      0         f
 88      0         f
```

I need to COUNT best ranks (using MAX(blogs_score) and MAX(blogs_score_time)) for each user from **Blogs table** and INSERT/UPDATE the **Users table** with the best ranks for the first 100 users of each gender with highest ranks, so the result should be:

```
PRIMARY
 id  best_rank  gender
 11      2         m
 23      1         m
 51      2         f
 88      1         f
```

The Best Ranks supposed to be **for each gender**.

*The final idea is to show the Rank position in user's profile and once someone voted (`blogs_score` changes in the blogs table), the `best_rank` column in the `users` table must be updated with the new ranks recalculation for **ALL** 100 users who has the best ranks in particular gender group.*

How to adapt and fix this (not working) query to my needs?

```
 $sql->query("UPDATE users
                JOIN (SELECT b.users_id,
                             @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
                             MAX(blogs_score), MAX(blogs_score_time)
                      FROM blogs b
                             JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
                      ORDER BY  b.blogs_score DESC, p.blogs_score_time DESC LIMIT 100
                ) ranks ON (ranks.users_id = users.id)
             SET users.best_rank = ranks.rank");
```

Please help me with the query to solve it. I didn't find any similar solution on stackoverflow and it seems very complicated for me to write such a query alone.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: why would user id `11` have best rank of `2`?

Comment: @CodeGodie, because user id 11 has same score with user 23 but older date than user 23. I have added column `blogs_score_time` to prevent tie ranking. And the date 2015-09-10 means September 10.

Comment: so what about user `51`, why does that one have a `2` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie, because it is a rank of Female's group. As I mentioned above I have a Ranking board for each gender. One board for Females and another for Males and they have their own Best ranks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Here's my latest :)

I don't know how you want to use the date field, but would row_number with a partition do what you need to do?

```
declare @blogs table (blogs_id int, users_id int, blogs_score int, blogs_score_time datetime, gender char(1))

insert @blogs 
select 1, 11, 2852, '2015-09-09 5:21:51', 'm'
union all 
select 2, 23, 2146, '2015-09-10 7:31:54', 'm'
union all 
select 3, 23, 2146, '2015-09-10 7:32:26', 'm'
union all 
select 4, 23, 2852, '2015-09-10 4:42:15', 'm'
union all 
select 5, 51, 1793, '2015-09-11 8:15:55', 'f'
union all 
select 6, 88, 2947, '2015-09-11 9:33:18', 'f'


select top 100 
    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY GENDER ORDER BY BLOGS_SCORE DESC) [Rank],
    * 
from @blogs
order by blogs_score desc, blogs_score_time desc
```

Comment: Not really. Not from a select. I think the query supposed to be with a SELECT inside UPDATE. Concerning the second example, how to set the best ranks for each gender? WHERE gender = bt.gender?

Comment: if you're matching the user id to the id from the users table, you don't really care what gender they are. they should always match. 

if you match the blogs table to the users table by ID you're good. On that note, you might not even care to have the gender column on the blogs table. That makes me think a blog has a gender! 


If you are trying to show the best scores per gender, just select where blogs score = max(blogs score) group by gender.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You are right. And should I add LIMIT 100 near WHERE clause to set only for 100 users? Let me check your query how it works.

Comment: Yeah that will work. LIMIT is achieved by using 'SELECT TOP ' with a number of rows to limit to. It's slightly different from MySQL.

Comment: Something like a select top 100 .... from ... order by blogs_score desc

Comment: thank you for your example but when I execute the query it updates the users table with the best score of the user from the blogs table. And I need to count the rank from the the score.

Comment: OOOOH took me a second. So do you need the query to increment the number of times they have had a score in the top 100, or is 'best rank' their personal best of all time overall? Like "billy was number 1 once."

Comment: Well, I need a query to calculate the Rank from the max score AND max score_date and update this Rank in the users table every time when the score changes in the blogs table.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me, but this is not really what I'm expecting. Anyway, once again Thank you! Let me see if someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

To come up with your desired results I would use the following:

```
SELECT users_id, MAX(blogs_score), gender
FROM blogs
GROUP BY users_id, gender
ORDER BY blogs_score_time DESC
```

Result:

```
users_id  MAX(blogs_score) gender
88        2947             f      <-- first F
51        1793             f      <-- second F
23        2852             m      <-- first M
11        2852             m      <-- second M
```

Comment: Thank you CodeGodie for your example but I need to UPDATE the users table not to SELECT the blog. And I need not the highest score but the Rank from the score.

Comment: No prob. Run this code, then update whatever table you want using these results. Good luck